# Hard Disk:S.M.A.R.T. Stas BAD, Back up and replace

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata

I have an laptop top hard drive I was trying to use to my new media computer. The case is small and can accommodate for 2 2.5" drives, no 3.5" drives. I had been using the hard drive as storage hard drive until now. When I go to install Windows on the hard drive first I'm prompted at the bios of:

> Hard Disk:S.M.A.R.T. Stas BAD, Back up and replace.

And then again in the Windows Setup, informing me that the hard drive is bad. So I did a full format of the drive and tried again. Same error. So I took it out and hooked it back up to my other computer via an Sata usb adapter kit (maybe the cause?). The hard drive is recognized fine and when I scanned it for errors by going:

```
right click -> properties -> tools -> error checking
```

It returns that the hard drive is fine. I have tried 3 different SATA cables and multiple jumpers. When I plugged in my 1.5 tb 3.5" drive the computer that gives me the S.M.A.R.T. error on the 2.5" drive, recognizes it with no problems.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Your question is incredibly unclear.  "hen I plugged in my 1.5 tb 3.5" drive it recognizes it "  WHAT recognised it? What were you plugging it into. What is a "media computer".  "The case is small and can accommodate for 2 2.5" drives, no 3.5" drives" What case? The case for your big computer, or your laptop.. Are you trying the hard drive in a laptop internally, a desktop internally, and in USB externally.  Hard drives in USB ports are less fussy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the S.M.A.R.T. warning go away when your 2.5" drive is not connected?  If so, then take your 2.5" drive back to where you bought it from for a warranty replacement.  Just because you can't find bad sectors from another computer, it doesn't matter, the drive is reporting itself as having some sort of problem (include the exact error message for your vendor when returning the drive).

The reason your SATA-to-USB connector may not be reporting any S.M.A.R.T. errors is that many of those devices don't support S.M.A.R.T.

Also, as long as you're only connecting/disconnecting the SATA drive while everything's powered off, you should be able to safely assume that your drive wasn't damaged by any of your equipment.

Formatting the drive usually won't make a difference with regard to reducing bad sectors (although it can make the problem worse depending on the cause), but there is a software solution that does have an excellent success rate that may be helpful to you if your hard drive isn't under warranty:

SpinRite 6 by Steve Gibson
  http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.html

Comment: He said *bad* smart data. That's not the same as No smart data. Sure with USB you get no smart data. SMART data gives STATS, not really errors messages.

Comment: Spinrite is not well recommended by experts.. Scott Mueller in his book gives it some criticism. I did have a long discussion with somebody about it in comments , prior to the chat link appearing, and all the comments were deleted, it's not easy to find all the info though I did in the past. Also in the reviews he uses, people reviewing it repeat some false claims he makes.

Comment: "Formatting the drive usually won't make a difference with regard to reducing bad sectors (although it can make the problem worse depending on the cause), but there is a software solution "  No software does, maybe you read  his claim to make hard drive crashes a thing of the past.  No software does that. Besides the false claims.. Mueller gave it some technical criticism. If a hard drive is bad, get rid of it. And i'd add, hard drive recovery people wouldn't touch spinrite 'cos it writes to the drive.

Comment: Well, my experience with SpinRite has been that it can help to recover data from bad sectors (and I remember using it back in the terrible times of RLL and MFM in the 1980s to do just that).  Perhaps this is just "luck of the draw," I can't say for sure because each failure is unique, but the reasoning that Steve Gibson gives about the techniques that SpinRite employs seems sensible to me.

Comment: As for hanging on to bad drives, I'm not advocating that -- if a drive has a problem, just replace it.  If there's data that needs to be recovered, then SpinRite obviously isn't the only option, but in my view it can be a valid solution.